Disable button for 5 seconds with different label and change after it
I'm trying to create an intro in my shiny app using the rintrojs package with the introjs function. My goal is to create an intro where the first next button is disabled for 5 seconds and has a different label like 'Wait 5 seconds...'. It currently waits 5 seconds and changes from label but it isn't disabled during the 5 seconds. So you can still click on it. Here is a reproducible example:
library(shiny)
library(rintrojs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  introjsUI(),
  actionButton("start_intro", "Start Intro"),
  h1("Welcome to the Shiny App"),
  p("This is some description of the app.")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  steps <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      element = c(NA, "#start_intro"),
      intro = c("Welcome to the app! This first step has a custom button.",
                "This is the start button for the intro tour."),
      position = c("bottom", "bottom")
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$start_intro, {
    introjs(session, 
            options = list(
              steps = steps(),
              nextLabel = "Wait 5 seconds..." 
            ),
            events = list(
              "onbeforechange" = I("
                if (this._currentStep === 0) {
                  var that = this;
                  var nextButton = document.querySelector('.introjs-nextbutton');
                  
                  if (nextButton) {
                    nextButton.innerHTML = 'Wait 5 seconds...';  // Initial label
                    nextButton.disabled = true;                  // Disable the button
                  }
                  
                  setTimeout(function() {
                    that._options.nextLabel = 'next'; // Change label after 5 seconds
                    that._introItems[0].nextLabel = 'next';
                    var nextButton = document.querySelector('.introjs-nextbutton');
                    if (nextButton) {
                      nextButton.innerHTML = 'next';  // Update the label to 'next'
                      nextButton.disabled = false;    // Enable the button after 5 seconds
                    }
                  }, 5000); // 5 seconds delay
                }
              ")
            )
    )
  })
}
 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Output:

As you can see it create the 'Wait 5 seconds...' button which is also shown for 5 seconds, but it is not disabled during the 5 seconds. So I was wondering how we can create a button which changes from label after 5 seconds and is disabled during the 5 seconds?

In theory at least, nextButton.classList.add('introjs-disabled'); should do the job - that's the class making the "Back" button disabled - but I can only get it to work in the console

The first problem is that <a> elements don't have a disabled property. Second, nextButton is always NULL because the html isn't initially rendered - pop in a console.log('boop') to see what I mean. Consequently, you need to look for it after rendering is complete.
Substitute this in after var that = this;:
function waitForButton() {
  var nextButton = document.querySelector('.introjs-nextbutton');

if (nextButton) {
    nextButton.innerHTML = 'Wait 5 seconds for real now...';
    nextButton.classList.add('introjs-disabled');
    nextButton.style.pointerEvents = 'none'; // Disable click
  } else {
    setTimeout(waitForButton, 100); // Retry after 100ms if button is not found
  }
}
waitForButton()

setTimeout(function() {
  that._options.nextLabel = 'next'; // Change label after 5 seconds
  that._introItems[0].nextLabel = 'next';
  var nextButton = document.querySelector('.introjs-nextbutton');
  if (nextButton) {
    nextButton.innerHTML = 'next';  // Update the label to 'next'
    nextButton.classList.remove('introjs-disabled');   // Enable the button after 5 seconds
    nextButton.style.pointerEvents = 'auto'; // Enable click
  }
}, 5000); // 5 seconds delay


Thank you for your answer! I tried implementing the code but now the intro doesn't start anymore when clicking on the start intro button. I'm not sure if I substituted the code correctly.

Sorry I reformatted it and mangled it - should work now

Thank you for your reformat. This looks already better and almost works. Now the button looks disabled but when you click on it, it still works somehow.

Ah so it does. Switching nextButton.style.pointerEvents between none and auto fixes that. Added a more complete answer!
